# mysql GROUP BY to sort and display the output

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a multi-user page where user posts something, and posts are grouped and sorted by the user id and display only several of them on main page.

I have a table where it stores user information (id, password etc) and another table that stores the posts (content, post id, poster id).

What I'm stuck at and wondering is that I know I should use GROUP BY or DISTINCT to do it, but when I use it, it would only display only one post on each user. and it will output them all in one row.

```
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM post GROUP BY author_id") or die(mysqli_error($con));

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                $title =  $row['title'];
                $id =  $row['post_id'];
                $author = $row['author_id'];
                echo "\n<div class=\"thumb\">";
                echo "<p>$author</p>";
                echo "<div class=\"thumb-title\">$title</div>";
                echo "\n</div>";        
        }
```

Output

```
User1 User2
Post1 post2
```

I want this to be like

```
User1 
Post1 Post2 Post3 (see more)

User2
Post1 Post2 Post3 (see more)
...
```

Comment: You need to add another column in Group By such as post_id for example: `SELECT * FROM post GROUP BY author_id, post_id` try it and let me know.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`. You probably just want to `ORDER BY author_id`; then in your loop only display the `thumb` div when the value of `$author` changes

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score -2):

Your table contain one to many relation between your authors and posts tables. I means your user1 can have multiple post like:

```
user1 -> post1
user1 -> post2
user1 -> post3
```

So now your fetching your posts by grouping author_id, so mysql will return single row related to each author in your database table.

you can't get output what expected by doing this.

try like this:

```
$users = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM authors") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($users)){
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author_id = {$user['id']}") or 
 die(mysqli_error($con));

    $author = $user['id'];
    echo "\n<div class=\"thumb\">";
    echo "<p>$author</p>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $title =  $row['title'];
        $id =  $row['post_id'];

        echo "<div class=\"thumb-title\">$title</div>";           
    }

    echo "\n</div>";  

}
```

Comment: Don't use two queries where one will suffice , and see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)